# "Allow customer users to change case statuses” missing from Community Settings

Tags: community, case, customer-community, partner-communities

Steps in salesforce docs:

```
Communities Settings.
2. Select Allow customer users to change case statuses.
3. Click Save
```

The problem is that the setting listed in step 2 does not appear on the Communities Settings page at all in any of my orgs. Any info would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's mine.
The setting looks like it only affects "Customer Community Plus" users using the Salesforce + VF tabs template.

[image: Community Settings]

Comment: Ah okay thank you, I think we are missing the “plus” license.